# Is meat eating allowed?

Tags: food, non-vegetarian, meat

I am on a quest to understand religions more deeply.

I have one simple question that is meat eating allowed in Hinduism? Are there any instances mentioned in any of the scriptures which talk about meat eating?
Also are there any mentions of texts where meat eating is banned?

I am asking this question because I remember that somewhere I came to know that there are instances where meat eating is mentioned in the Hindu scriptures and I just want to confirm if that's true.

Comment: I do not have proper references, but meat eating is allowed for everyone. But for kshatriya and Sudra, it is more suitable to consume meat because of the nature of the Varna involves doing more physical activities than other two varnas.

Comment: Check the following link .. you will find many helpful answers --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-vegetarian

Answer (score 0):

I am posting one Manu Smriti verse on meat eating.

> 56. **There is no sin in eating meat**, in (drinking) spirituous liquor, and in carnal intercourse, for that is the natural way of created
>     beings, but abstention brings great rewards.

**Manu Smriti 5.56**